# IndexError: list index out of range zigzagTraverse: Recursive Solution

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, matrix, return

Write a function that takes in an n x m two-dimensional array (that can be
square-shaped when n == m) and returns a one-dimensional array of all the
array's elements in zigzag order.

Zigzag order starts at the top left corner of the two-dimensional array, goes
down by one element, and proceeds in a zigzag pattern all the way to the
bottom right corner.

I am attempting to implement a recursive solution and I can successfully build the output array,
however, I receive the following error.

num = array[row][col]
IndexError: list index out of range

```
# Time: O(n) | # Space: O(n)
def zigzagTraverse_recursion(array):
    zigzag_traverse = []
    zigzag(0, 0, True, array, zigzag_traverse)
    return zigzag_traverse

def zigzag(row, col, down, array, zigzag_traverse):
    last_row = len(array) - 1
    last_col = len(array[0]) - 1
    if row > last_row and col > last_col:
        return

    num = array[row][col]
    zigzag_traverse.append(num)

    if down:
        if row == last_row:
            down = False
            col += 1

        elif col == 0:
            down = False
            row += 1

        else:
            row += 1
            col -= 1

    else:
        if col == last_col:
            down = True
            row += 1

        elif row == 0:
            down = True
            col += 1

        else:
            row -= 1
            col += 1

    zigzag(row, col, down, array, zigzag_traverse)
```

Comment: `if row > last_row and col > last_col:` are you sure about this condition? What if the array is very long and little tall and you have a high row (height) number?

Answer (score 1):

You are really over-complicating the solution to this problem. There are two possible actions to do at each step:

- Go right (col += 1)
- Go down (row += 1)

You just need to perform one of these actions depending on the current state, then swap the state for the next call. Here is the simplified code:

```
# Time: O(n) | # Space: O(n)
def zigzagTraverse_recursion(array):
    zigzag_traverse = []
    zigzag(0, 0, True, array, zigzag_traverse, "down")
    return zigzag_traverse

def zigzag(row, col, down, array, zigzag_traverse, state):
    last_row = len(array) - 1
    last_col = len(array[0]) - 1
    if row > last_row or col > last_col:
        return

    num = array[row][col]
    zigzag_traverse.append(num)
    print(locals())
    
    if state == "right":
        col += 1
    elif state == "down":
        row += 1

    if state == "down":
        state = "right"
    elif state == "right":
        state = "down"
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid state")

    zigzag(row, col, down, array, zigzag_traverse, state)

print(zigzagTraverse_recursion([[1, 3, 4, 10],
                                [2, 5, 9, 11],
                                [6, 8, 12, 15],
                                [7, 13, 14, 16]]))
```

The output:

```
[1, 2, 5, 8, 12, 14, 16]
```

---

Also keep in mind that for this problem an iterative solution would be much simpler and cleaner. You could go down or right depending if a counting variable is even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go for an iterative approach?

Using a boolean:

```py
def zigzag(array):
    zigzag_traverse, i, j, right = [], 0, 0, False
    while i < len(array) and j < len(array[0]):
        zigzag_traverse.append(array[i][j])
        i += not right
        j += right
        right = not right
    return zigzag_traverse
```

Or done differently by using arithmetic to do the indexing:

```py
def zigzag(array):
    zigzag_traverse, s = [], 0
    while (i := s // 2) < len(array) and (j := (s+1) // 2) < len(array[0]):
        zigzag_traverse.append(array[i][j])
        s += 1
    return zigzag_traverse
```